# How to change date format in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I change the date in this format: 2015-01-12T15: 40: 18Z

to  this format 2015-01-05 03:39:01?

I do not know how to do it in js

Thank you very much

Comment: Firstly, those times are different, so I'm not sure what you are asking. Where is the code you've tried?

Comment: Yes it is different this is just an example

Comment: I've always opted for momentjs http://momentjs.com/ when dealing with dates in JS

Answer (score 0):

```
var mydate = new Date(form.startDate.value);
var month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"][mydate.getMonth()];
var str = month + ' ' + mydate.getFullYear();
```